# How to serialize GET and SET using igbinary inside go redis client

Tags: go, redis, igbinary

I have a php service and a golang service. I set the value of redis in the php service and use igbinary. How to correctly GET this value in golang service.

Answer (score 0):

`igbinary` of php sets a [binary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.igbinary.php) value, you can read the binary value into array of `[]byte` in go.

```
response,err:=redisClient.Get(ctx,"key").Bytes()
```

here response bytes can be unmarshalled into proper struct to get values.

Comment: I used php to set the value of a key in redis to be "igbinary", but the value obtained by golang in redis is "\x00\x00\x00\x02\x11\bigbinary". I can't get the correct value.

Comment: depends on the binary data you have stored, what exactly is the data, before it is converted to binary.

Comment: [php]

$rds = new \Redis();
$rds->connect('127.0.0.1',6379,5);
$rds->setOption(\Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, \Redis::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY);
$rds->set('test_igbinary_key','igbinary');

[golang]

rds := redis.NewClient(options)
val := rds.Get(ctx, "test_igbinary_key")
b, _ := val.Bytes()
fmt.Println(b)
fmt.Println(string(b))
fmt.Printf("%#+v\n", string(b))

[result]

[0 0 0 2 17 8 105 103 98 105 110 97 114 121]
gbinary
"\x00\x00\x00\x02\x11\bigbinary"

Comment: The value set in redis is 'igbinary'

Comment: as you can see `string(b)` gives you the value. If the value is a json, you will unmarshal it.